# Updated- different problem, resolved. (original - fetch resolve json differently when using promise vs async/await)

Tags: javascript, json

UPDATE 11/28:

Problem resolved. It was in fact a completely different problem, irrelevant to fetch/ajax/etc, but unwanted object update via reference.

What misled me was that the actual code I use has a subsequent step after console.log. That subsequent step altered the data json, and as a consequence console.log value changed. It's fixed by deep clone the json.

What remains unsure to me is that why console.log comes before the data alteration but is affected -- guess console.log is async in this case.

===================
Original:

Super weird problem. My frontend needs to GET data from backend, so I used fetch in a promise chaining style, such as

```
fetch(myUrl, {credntials: 'include'})
  .then(res=>{
    if(res.status==200){
      return res.json()
    }
    else{
      return null
    }
  })
  .then(json=>{
    if(json){
      console.log(json)
    }
  })
```

Seems to be working fine and I got some data back. However, I noticed that the resolved JSON is different from the expected response from backend. For example, the backend outputs `{'a': {'aa':1, 'bb':1}}`, and the resolved `res.json()` gives me something like `{'a': {'aa':2, 'bb':1}}`. The change seems to be inconsistent, I got different `res.json()` value when tried again and again.

I then tried several different way to GET data:

1) typed in url in browser address bar => got correct data

2) use jQuery ajax method instead of fetch => got correct data

3) change promise chaining to async/await => this got correct data too!

```
let resp = await fetch(myUrl, {credentials: 'include'})
let json = await resp.json()
console.log(json)
```

4) tried the promise chained fetch, still incorrect data!

Super confused. Am I using fetch wrong? Is it a bug? Is it the browser? Is it the polyfill (I'm using `"whatwg-fetch": "3.0.0"`, but on Chrome, Mac, which in theory the polyfill should not affect anything at all)? Is it response header settings (Django, JsonResponse)? Has anyone had similar experience?

Update:
attach the headers

```
Request URL: ...
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 27 Nov 2019 19:39:26 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.6
Content-Type: application/json
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 1559
Vary: Origin, Cookie

Request Headers:
GET ... HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/...
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7,zh;q=0.6
Cookie: ...
```

**When I check the `Preview` and `Response` in chrome developer tools, both of them show correct data. However the `console.log(json)` line outputs differently.**

Comment: I doubt the parser is altering the data. Might be caching of data?

Comment: It would be informative to load the request/response into Fiddler and see what all the headers have to say re: caching and payload.

Comment: @Amy added the headers in updates, do they make sense?

Comment: @epascarello is there a way to clear caching? but then why using async/await gives me the right response...

Comment: This seems most likely to be a coincidence - how exhaustively have you tested to ensure that it's *only* promise chaining that produces wrong results? Have you tried async/await 10x in a row? Promise chaining and then async, and vice versa? There should be no functional difference between the two - async/await is basically just sugar for promise chaining in the first place.

Comment: @Klaycon tried another 13 times, async/await always gave me correct one while promise chaining did not. doesn't seems like coincidence now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that original question is misleading. Found the real cause and resolved. See updates on 11/28 in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a typo, credentials is spelled differently between both requests you listed here:

`fetch(myUrl, {**credntials:** 'include'})`

vs here:

`let resp = await fetch(myUrl, {**credentials:** 'include'})`

If this doesn't resolve the issue, let me know but it seems extremely unlikely that this is a difference of async/await vs regular promises.

Comment: Oh it is a typo. actual code was typed correctly and still have the error.

Comment: tried 20+ times together, same results. But the `preview` and `response` in chrome developer tool for the two ways are indeed the same. The console log outputs differently which is very weird.